# Relation does not exist when trying to grant privileges

Tags: postgresql, vagrant

I'm currently writing a script to build my vagrant box. I got PHP 7 and some other tools installed, as well as PostgreSQL, but when creating the database and trying to grant privileges I'm getting the following error

`ERROR:  relation "projectname" does not exist`

This is my script (the important stuff)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
projectname='projectname'
echo "Initializing database"
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER $projectname WITH PASSWORD 'xxxx';"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE $projectname;"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $projectname TO $projectname;"
```

Everything works until the last step

`sudo -u postgres psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $projectname TO $projectname;"`

When trying this out, I'm getting the above error. I also tried to write it manually

`sudo -u postgres psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON projectname TO projectname;"`

Same error.

I also tried to wrap it in quotation marks

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'feedparser' TO 'feedparser';"

sudo -u postgres psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \"feedparser\" TO \"feedparser\";"
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Documentation about [GRANT PRIVILEGES](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-grant.html) says that your version GRANT command is suitable for grant rights to table. If you want to grant rights to database you should use `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE projectname TO projectname;`. Below I show the results of this commands:

```
postgres=# CREATE USER projectname WITH PASSWORD 'projectname';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE projectname;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON projectname TO projectname;
ERROR:  relation "projectname" does not exist
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE projectname TO projectname;
GRANT
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I found it out by myself later, but since I didn't write it somewhere I'm gonna accept your answer. As you said: I only had to add DATABASE to the query and it worked.